# Decomposing the fraction $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}$

Tags: combinatorics

The question is so simple. We want to decompose the fraction $(\frac{1}{1-x})(\frac{1}{1-x^2})(\frac{1}{1-x^3})$

We also have the answer which is :

$\frac{\frac{1}{6}}{(1-x)^3}+\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{\frac{1}{4}}{1-x^2}+\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{1-x^3}$

The problem is not finding those numbers $\frac{1}{6},\dots$
We don't know why the original fraction is decomposed to these special fractions with these special denominators ? For example, why not decomposing it into $3$ fractions with denominators $1-x$,$1-x^2$,$1-x^3$?  At first, i tried to solve the question this way ... but i couldn't find the proper numerator for those $3$ fractions. Then i took a look at the answer and i was shocked !

I want explanation. This is not a homework. I have the answer. I can't understand it.

Note : The original question wanted to find the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in this fraction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using the normal partial fraction method, you should get that $A, B$ and $C$ are zero. Hence, you need to find other fractions, the easier way is to square one of the denominators you already have

Comment: I don't see why this is the answer.  The $\frac{1/4}{1-x^2}$ can be decomposed further.  So can the last fraction.

Comment: To explain where the $(1-x)^3$ comes from, notice that$$1-x^2=(1-x)(1+x)\qquad\quad1-x^3=(1-x)(1+x+x^2)$$

Comment: @SimpleArt the original question had something to do with the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in that fraction ... doesn't that help to explain ?

Comment: @SimpleArt a decomposition of this form (i.e in terms of $\frac{1}{1-x^k}$ ) is more useful than a full decomposition. This allow one to extract the coefficients of $x^n$ more easily. I wish I knew how to do this a week ago when I need to decompose $\frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^2)(1-x^3)}$. Let's say it isn't pleasant.

Comment: @achillehui Haha, I'll keep that in mind.